# Roboto font in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

I would like to use "Roboto" font in prestashop. I've received design in .psd files and graphic designer used fonts "Roboto Medium" and "Roboto Regular". Do i understand correctly, that when i want to use Roboto Normal I can apply:

```
font- family: "Roboto"
font-weight: 400
```

and when i want to use Roboto Medium I should apply:

```
font- family: "Roboto"
font-weight: 500
```

In other words, are weights 400 and 500 respectively equal to Roboto Normal and Roboto Medium?

Comment: I think you need to load those two fonts at first by `@font-face`, so you can specify the `font-weight` of each one within the `@font-face` block.

Comment: @HashemQolami, I did this - I pasted <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> to head

Comment: That is correct, JaroslawRewers. No need for @font-face.

Comment: no, normal and medium , as well as thin and bold, are different roboto font variations, corresponding to different ttf files. By setting the font weight u just set that, the weight, to the default variation weight. You do not change the font appearance

Answer (score 21):

Make sure you are closing your CSS lines.

```
font-family: "Roboto";
font-weight: 400;
```

Yes, your weights are correct.

```
font-weight: 400; //normal
font-weight: 500; //medium
font-weight: 700; //bold
```

Please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) regarding `font-weight`, it's not always available depending on the font. But, according to [Google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto), you should be able to use those weights without a problem.

Answer (score 6):

I was a little confused by this initially as well.

I had a client request and per their style guide I needed to set fonts accordingly for "Roboto", "Roboto Medium", "Roboto Light", etc.

Looking at Google's font site ( https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto ) They show the "Roboto" font, then examples of each variation of it "Medium", "Light", etc.

But it's not obvious that this involves two settings in CSS. My initial thought was that you set it like this:

```
* {font-family: 'Roboto Light', 'Roboto Medium', 'Roboto', etc}
```

But after experimenting and a little research, it involves two settings, one to specify the core "family" then the variation is the "weight" like this:

```
.Roboto{font-family:'Roboto';font-weight:400;} /* 400 is industry standard for normal */

.RobotoLight{font-familiy:'Roboto';font-weight:300;} /* 300 is industry standard for normal */

.RobotoMedium{font-family:'Roboto';font-weight:500;} /* 500 is industry standard for normal */
```

Comment: Additional notes: If we have to specify the weight via CSS, I'm not sure why (when using Google fonts) we have to also 'download' the appropriate weights we want to use (I thought fonts were just a "font" and CSS weight controlled intensity similar to applying BOLD). So I thought download generically, weight accordingly. Not sure why that's not the case.

Here is how I'm obtaining the Roboto font in light, normal, and medium weights:

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: that's because for fontset like roboto, medium size is also visible different in shape and not only in weight from normal and bold.